# How to idealy setup Model For default items in Djaago

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django application, where the business can add items in Item Model. Also, some of the common items should be there in the database which is provided by the admins(me) which will be shown to the users and they can add that if they want. If the select that item a new item will be created in the database with values from the selected item and the user field in the item model will point to the user who created it. From that instant, the user has a copy of that item under their control. They can edit values if they want.

How to implement this system. I have two options

1. Adding the common items in the item model itself with user field equals to null, and maybe add another field to identify it is added bt admin.
2. Create a separate model for default Items.

Which is the ideal method? Or is there an alternate method?